# Why study english?

Tags: grammaticality, idiomatic-language

Is the following grammatical and idiomatic (verb directly follow why) for both writing and speaking english

> Why study english?
>
> Why go home early?

As I normally use the following format:

> Why we need to study english?
>
> Why we need to go home early?

Comment: I am not going to provide a formal answer because there is an aspect that I am unsure of. What I am sure about is that "Why study English" is grammatical and idiomatic but rare and that "Why we need to study English" is ungrammatical if intended as a **question**. The usual way to ask that question is "Why do we study English?" What I am unsure of is what circumstances lead to using the rare form of question instead of the common form of question. Sorry for being unable to give a complete answer.

Answer (score 2):

They are simply shorter ways of asking those questions, which could have *I, you* or *we* as subject.

"Why study English when Spanish would be more useful to you?" (note that names of languages take a capital letter).

"Why go home early when the party's just getting started?"

Incidentally, your longer versions should be "Why *do* we need to...?"